# Extracting the color of Excel worksheet tabs using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Is there any way to get the information about the color of a worksheet tab using xlrd.  For a worksheet object it is straightforward to get the name listed in the tab but not the color of the tab itself.